# Where can I find examples of statistics projects?

Tags: reference-request, statistics

I am going to teach an undergraduate statistics course for the first time next semester. I would like students to do a project by applying some of the things they learned to real-world data. Is there any sources (books, websites) with suitable examples for something likes this?

The topics covered in the course will be

- Prior and Posterior Distributions, Conjugate Prior Distributions, Bayes Estimators
- Maximum Likelihood Estimators
- The Sampling Distribution of a Statistic, The Chi-Square Distributions, The t-distributions, Confidence
  Intervals, Fisher Information
- Testing Simple Hypotheses, Uniformly Most Powerful Tests, Uniformly Most Powerful Tests, The t Test, Comparing Two Normal Distributions
- Goodness-of-Fit, Contingency Tables, Tests of Homogeneity
- Linear Regression

---

Update: One idea I have is to ask students to find a paper with published data and verify the statistics done in this paper is accurate.  Is this a good idea?

Comment: Have you already checked out the resources at https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/7976/12619 and found them lacking?

Comment: @MatthewDaly Thanks. That post is very helpful. I think it is enough for me.